# JPA references not loaded before committing transaction

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager

I am creating parent and child entities in same transaction but if i see parent entity before commit. child object references are not shown in parent, though while creating child entity i have given parent's reference in it.

For example I have following entities:

- Product
- Category

A **product** can have one or many **categories**. I have created bidirectional relationship between them as below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PRODUCT")
public class Product {
 @Id
 @Column(name="PRODUCT_ID")
 int productId;
 ....
 .... 
 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", orphanRemoval = true)
 private Set<Category> categories = new HashSet<>();
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "CATEGORY")
public class Category {
 @Id
 int categoryId;
 ....
 ....

 @ManyToOne(optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 @JoinColumn(name = "PRODUCT_ID")
 private Product product;
}
```

In below method I am creating both entites within same transaction and when i load **Product** before commit it shows there is no **Category** associated with it. However if i load **Product** after the transaction is committed then it shows reference to category. Can i have relationships build between entities before entitymanager is flushed?

```
@transactional
public void saveData() {
  Product product = new Product();
  product.setId(1);
  em().persist(porduct);
  Category category = new Category();
  category.setId(1);
  category.set(product) 
  em().persist(category);

  Product persistedProduct = em().findById(1);
  //Why below statement prints size of categories zero
  System.out.println(persistedProduct.getCategories.size())
}
```

Comment: Do you see the productId in **CATEGORY** table for **PRODUCT_ID** column in the database after the transaction

Comment: Yes, after the transaction i see productid in the category table. Also if i load fetch product entity after the transaction is committed then i see associated category in it.

Comment: It is better to save in single step. i.e save only PRODUCT with its CATEGORIES in single persist.

Comment: The problem is the owner of the relationship(where the foreinkey exists) is Student, so before commiting, the product doesnot know about the category.

Comment: You are not adding `Category` to the inverse collection (`Set` in `Product`) i.e. you are not a maintaining bidirectional relationship in this case which the JPA provider itself is not responsible for. There should be a statement like `product.getCategories().add(category);`